# Make a folder hidden using java 6 in Windows, but it failed

Tags: java

I run my class in the command line, it's ok, but When I package my project as the service of Windows, it's failed. Anyone get the reason? 
My service run as the System user, the tempFolder was created as System user.
There is my code, and I didn't get any exception and error.

```
(!tempFolder.exists()){
            if(tempFolder.mkdirs()){
                String operatingSystemName = System.getProperty("os.name");
                if (operatingSystemName != null
                        && operatingSystemName.startsWith(WINDOWS_FAMILY)) {
                    String string = " attrib " + tempFolder.getAbsolutePath()+ " +h";
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                throw new Exception("Can't create temp folder - " + tempFolder.toString());
            }
```

Comment: You probably not have the security privileges to create a directory and or change it's attributes

Comment: My service run as the System user. Do you think is ok?

Comment: Not sure what privileges the system user actually has.  Might depend on where you are trying to create the directory

Comment: This folder was created by System user. And I checked the Security tab in the Properties of the this folder. The System in the "Group or user names:"

Comment: Can you hide it using the command line (as the system user)?

Comment: I am not sure, how reproduce it? How to run it as System user in command line?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter **+s**

```
String string = " attrib " + tempFolder.getAbsolutePath()+ " +s +h";
```

**+s** : Used to set the file attribute as a system file.

**Parameters of attrib command**

**+r** : Used to set the file attribute as read-only.

**-r** : Used to clear the read-only file attribute.

**+a** : Used to set the file attribute as archive.

**-a** : Used to clear the archive file attribute.

**+s** : Used to set the file attribute as a system file.

**-s** : Used to clear the system file attribute.

**+h** : Used to make the file attribute as hidden not visible to the user.

**-h** : Used to clear the hidden file attribute.

Comment: This folder which I want to hide, it's not the system folder. It's just the production level. I don't want to make it as the system level, just hide it is fine.

Comment: BTW do you mean the System user just can hide the system level folder?